# Sexual Reproduction in Humans

Tags: human-biology, reproduction, human-physiology, sexual-reproduction

Is the human egg cell (ova) considered motile? We know that is is not actively motile but it is transferred via the fallopian tube to the uterus. Does that make it motile?

Comment: Hi! Please take a brief tour of the site (you'll even get a badge to prove it!). Feel free to nose around and check out the help center and such as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

The fallopian tubes, also known as uterine tubes are uterine appendages, lined from inside with ciliated simple columnar epithelium, leading from the ovaries of female mammals into the uterus, via the uterotubal junction. They enable the passage of egg cells from the ovaries to the uterus.

The egg cell is typically not capable of active movement and hence not motile